# Twenty Twenty edit "Read more" text

Tags: customization

I am using wordpress Twenty Twenty theme. So I am trying to change the "Read more" text after each blog and this is the function i am trying to do it with.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

I found this function (below) in `functions.php`, which I **think** is responsible for generating the "Read more" text?

```
function twentytwenty_read_more_tag( $html ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<a(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/iU', sprintf( '<div class="read-more-button-wrap"><a$1><span class="faux-button">$2</span> <span class="screen-reader-text">"%1$s"</span></a></div>', get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) ), $html );
}

add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'twentytwenty_read_more_tag' );
```

I changed the first function add_filter to match the second one so now I have this code.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'twentytwenty_read_more_tag' );
```

But the text isn't changing and if I change the function `modify_read_more_link` to match the original function I get this error.

> Cannot redeclare **twentytwenty_read_more_tag()** (previously declared in /home3/shroomy/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/functions.php:572)

I don't think I even need to change the function name, but I am completely new to this.

Comment: make sure that the name of the function is exaclty the same as the second argument of the 'add_filter' https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/. you have a mixup in your last posted code. generally, your first posted code should have worked - tested by adding it to the end of functions.php of the theme Twenty Twenty...although you would lose the formatting of the original 'continue reading' link

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: then there might be other issues in your setup, like interference with other plugins or so...please consider to post in the dedicated Twenty Twenty theme's forum at https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentytwenty/

Comment: Thank you for the idea, i will try to ask there.